# TreeView - множественное выделение по типу ноды

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, .net-core

**Предисловие**

Решаю для меня сложную задачку по визуализации данных, проект большой и требует рефакторинга, застрял. Не могу рефакторить, пока не приму архитектурное решение по данной фиче. Поэтому создал отдельный демо-проект, чтобы воспроизвести то, что мне требуется.

Это не простой `TreeView` с мультиселектом, поэтому готовые решения с гитхаба мне не подошли, к тому же мне требуется особая визуализация, которой я уже смог добиться в XAML разметке. Проблема только с логикой.

**Задача**

- Дано дерево элементов, каждая нода имеет свой айдишник и тип.
- `TreeView` отображает эти ноды в виде визуального дерева. Ноды могут быть выбранными (активными) или не выбранными (не активными).
- По умолчанию выбраны ноды верхнего уровня.
- Одновременно может быть выбрана только одна нода для каждого типа. **- вот здесь застрял**
- Всегда должно быть выбрано постоянное количество нод, сколько типов нод присутствует в дереве - столько и выбрано.
- Отдельно должна формироваться коллекция с айдишниками выбранных. На основе этой коллекции я буду заполнять другой контрол контентом.

*Для видимости, вот реализация интерфейса INPC*

```csharp
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

**Данные**

```csharp
public enum TreeNodeType
{
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue
}

public class TreeItem : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private TreeNodeType _nodeType;
    private int _nodeId;
    private ObservableCollection<TreeItem> _items;
    private bool _selected;
    private bool _active;

    public int NodeId
    {
        get => _nodeId;
        set
        {
            _nodeId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public TreeNodeType NodeType
    {
        get => _nodeType;
        set
        {
            _nodeType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<TreeItem> Items // TreeViewItem.ItemsSource
    {
        get => _items;
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public bool Selected // TreeViewItem.IsSelected
    {
        get => _selected;
        set 
        {
            _selected = value;
            Active = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public bool Active // моя попытка выделять элемент
    {
        get => _active;
        set
        {
            if (value) _active = !_active;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**View Model**

```csharp
public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<TreeItem> _treeItems;
    private ObservableCollection<int> _selectedItems;

    public ObservableCollection<TreeItem> TreeItems
    {
        get => _treeItems;
        set
        {
            _treeItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<int> SelectedItems // сюда хочу записать айдищшники выбранных нод
    {
        get => _selectedItems;
        set
        {
            _selectedItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        // тестовые данные
        TreeItems = new ObservableCollection<TreeItem>
        {
            new TreeItem
            {
                NodeId = 0,
                NodeType = TreeNodeType.Red,
                Items = new ObservableCollection<TreeItem>
                {
                    new TreeItem
                    {
                        NodeId = 1,
                        NodeType = TreeNodeType.Red,
                        Items = new ObservableCollection<TreeItem>
                        {
                            new TreeItem { NodeId = 2, NodeType = TreeNodeType.Green },
                            new TreeItem { NodeId = 3, NodeType = TreeNodeType.Red }
                        }
                    },
                    new TreeItem { NodeId = 4, NodeType = TreeNodeType.Red }
                },
                Selected = true
            },
            new TreeItem
            {
                NodeId = 5,
                NodeType = TreeNodeType.Blue,
                Items = new ObservableCollection<TreeItem>
                {
                    new TreeItem
                    {
                        NodeId = 6,
                        NodeType = TreeNodeType.Blue,
                        Items = new ObservableCollection<TreeItem>
                        {
                            new TreeItem { NodeId = 7, NodeType = TreeNodeType.Blue }
                        }
                    },
                    new TreeItem { NodeId = 8, NodeType = TreeNodeType.Green }
                },
                Selected = true
            },
            new TreeItem
            {
                NodeId = 9,
                NodeType = TreeNodeType.Green,
                Selected = true
            }
        };

        SelectedItems = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    }
}
```

**Разметка**

```xaml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TreeItems}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Items}"/>
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Selected}"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Margin="2" >
                                    <Border BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2">
                                        <Border.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Active}" Value="True">
                                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Border.Style>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Rectangle Width="30" Height="30" Margin="2">
                                                <Rectangle.Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NodeType}" Value="Red">
                                                                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NodeType}" Value="Green">
                                                                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green"/>
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NodeType}" Value="Blue">
                                                                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue"/>
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                                    </Style>
                                                </Rectangle.Style>
                                            </Rectangle>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NodeId}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.Resources>
        <TreeView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemsPanel>
    </TreeView>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems}"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, куда копать? Как найти ранее выделенную ноду этого же типа, снять с нее выделение, и только после этого выделить текущую?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что то вы намудрили с этим Selected vs Active, по хорошему логику с отметками вынести куда то модель нужно и протестировать. Я то просто сделал ваш пример работоспособным. Что я сделал:

В главной модели добавил пару методов

```
    public void Deactive(TreeNodeType type)
    {
        if (TreeItems != null)
            foreach (var treeItem in TreeItems)
                Deactive(treeItem, type);
    }

    private void Deactive(TreeItem node, TreeNodeType type)
    {
        if (node.Active && node.NodeType == type)
        {
            node.Active = false;
        }

        if (node.Items != null)
            foreach (var item in node.Items)
                Deactive(item, type);
    }
```

Добавил в ноду ссылку на главную модель

```
public class TreeItem : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ....
    public MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; set; }
```

Чуть поправил логику на Selected/Active

```
    public bool Selected // TreeViewItem.IsSelected
    {
        get => _selected;
        set
        {
            _selected = value;
            if (value)
                Active = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public bool Active // моя попытка выделять элемент
    {
        get => _active;
        set
        {
            if (value) MainViewModel.Deactive(NodeType);
            _active = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Что вышло из этого

[image: ...]

Закинул что наклепал на [Github](https://github.com/tym32167/SO_Samples/tree/master/src/RU_1137568). Но повторюсь, я бы такую логику вынес куда то в модель, а то вся эта мешанина через лет 5 вам аукнется.

Comment: Работает, спасибо! Только cсылку на `MainViewModel` я сделал статичной, чтобы в каждый экземпляр ее не передавать. Осталось только актуальную коллекцию айдишников поддержать, чтобы не парсить дерево каждый раз при потребности ее использовать, но это уже просто, и я сделаю сам. По поводу выноса логики, я пока не вижу потребности, и вероятность, что она именно в этом месте когда-нибудь поменяется, нулевая, но идею понял и принял к сведению. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, хорошо, что заработало.